# Mutate multiple states from within useEffect causes react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning

Tags: reactjs

I am playing around with React Hooks. When the button is clicked, I want to increment a counter. After the counter was incremented, the application should not allow further increments until clicked is reset to false.

I came up with this:

```
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (clicked) {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setClicked(false);
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, [clicked]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Clicked: {String(clicked)}</p>
      <p>Counter: {counter}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It actually works. However React is complaining with following warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'counter'. Either
>   include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a
>   functional update 'setCounter(c => ...)' if you only need 'counter' in
>   the 'setCounter' call. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

When I add the counter to the dependencies, useEffect will get into an infinite loop, because *clicked* is true and setCounter was called from within useEffect.

I want the counter only to be incremented, when *clicked* changed from false to true. That works if the dependency list only contains *clicked*, but React complains about that.

Try out for yourself: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-shadow-7xesm

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-cache-r93x8

Comment: Just a question, what's wrong with doing `setCounter(counter => counter + 1)` this?

Comment: `the application should not allow further increments until clicked is reset to false` when does this happen? is the timeout request required?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try replacing setCounter(counter + 1) with this:

```
setCounter(counter => counter + 1)
```

Like the warning says. Should solve it.

Comment: Thank you Craig. In VS code the warning is actually displayed without the suggestion setCounter(c => ..), like this "React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'foo' and 'bar'. Either include them or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps" In the sandbox however the solution is already in the warning, haha.

Comment: just want to say that this method is used for async issues and not on sync with variable dependency issue

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with infinite loop will be gone if you remove the timeout. (btw what is it for? Are you trying to implement a debounce or throttle?)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (clicked) {
      setClicked(false);
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }
  }, [clicked, counter]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Clicked: {String(clicked)}</p>
      <p>Counter: {counter}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thank you! How would you realize a debounce of the click?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-bas-lnqql .. moved from using `useEffect` to `useCallback`. your `useEffect` only triggers once since the dependency only changes once(on first click: this is settings click from false to true).